# What is simplest way to convert :pluck or :collect results to array of strings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collect, pluck

I have a model called Record and belongs Product model,

the `price` column type is hexadecimal. Rails already convert it to string in view. But I wanna get them in my console queries.

Example code for pluck:

```
Product.first.records.pluck(:price)
```

This query displays the values in array as hexadecimal. There is a method called `to_sentences`  for pluck values but its not enough for my case.

The problem is same in `collect` method:

```
Product.first.records.collect(&:price)
```

What is the pluck query to display my hexadecimal data as array of strings like:

```
["45,46","75,42"]
```

Comment: You sure you know what "hexadecimal" means?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Product.first.records.pluck(:price).map(&:to_s)
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
Product.first.records.pluck(:price).join(',')
```